# Hide MatPaginator details

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Im trying to hide the strings that been added automatically by MatPaginator (Items per page: 1 1 – 1 of 2), I try to do the CSS way by setting `display:none;` or `display:none !important;` to the container classes but this didn't work:

```
.mat-paginator-page-size{
    display: none !important;
}

.mat-paginator-range-label{
    display: none !important;
}
```

I want only the next and previous arrows to show up without any other details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `::ng-deep` in front of both:

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-page-size{
    display: none !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-paginator-range-label{
    display: none !important;
}
```

`::ng-deep` force style to child components.

Note that for Angular 15 or later, the class names have been updated to the following: `.mat-mdc-paginator-range-label` and `mat-mdc-paginator-page-size`. See: https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#library-wide-changes

> Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely
> disables view-encapsulation for that rule. Any style with ::ng-deep
> applied becomes a global style. In order to scope the specified style
> to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include
> the :host selector before ::ng-deep. If the ::ng-deep combinator is
> used without the :host pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into
> other components.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: It works, thank you can explain what's ::ng-deep please

Comment: @S4L4H added explanation.

Comment: This is a bad answer in that while it works, it will also hide the paginator size on all other Material tables in your application. There are better answers below.

Comment: This solution works and it's the only way to hide the page numbering `1 of 1`. Bleeding of the selector can be isolated making the CSS selector more specific. `!important` is not required, tested and working also without it.

Answer (score 9):

The correct use for this property is:

```
<mat-paginator hidePageSize="true">
```

The reason is that you don't have to use brackets with a boolean value. Without initializing the boolean value in the TS file you may cause a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, which is when an expression value has been changed after change detection has completed. So if you decide use this property with brackets try this:

```
isHidePageSize: boolean = true;

<pre>
 <mat-paginator [hidePageSize]="isHidePageSize">
</pre>
```

This is also true of any other property with boolean values.

Comment: `hidePageSize` property hides only the `Items per page` label with the dropdown. It doesn't hide the page count (e.g. `1 of 1`).
It's not the solution to the problem of hiding the page numbers. A solution is only achievable via CSS with the `:host ::ng-deep .mat-paginator-range-label{ display: none; }` style.

Answer (score 6):

you can also create a CustomMatPaginatorIntl, and rewrite the function getRangeLabel. Create a CustomMatPaginatorIntl is only write a class that extends from MatPaginatorIntl

```
export class CustomMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  getRangeLabel=(page:number, pageSize:number, length:number)=>{
    return ''

  }
}
```

And use as provider

```
providers:[{provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: CustomMatPaginatorIntl}]
```

(if you use as provider in component all the paginator in component not show nothing, if you use as provider in the module, all the paginator in the components that belong to the module not show nothing)

NOTE. in the function:

```
//the first showed page is: (1+page*pageSize)
//the last showed page is : (1+page)*pageSize
//the total page is:length
//so we can return some like
return (1+page*pageSize)+' - '+(1+page)*pageSize+' pág/'+(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this properties in  mat-paginator [hidePageSize]="true" like

```
<mat-paginator [hidePageSize]="true" .....rest properties.....>
```

Comment: Page range can't be hidden using properties.